# Cannot import name 'plot_precision_recall_curve' from 'sklearn.metrics'

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

Hello i got trouble to import my package?cannot import name from sklearn

cannot import name 'plot_precision_recall_curve' from 'sklearn.metrics' (\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics_*init*_.py)

i try uninstall and install again pip install scikit-learn still not working at VScode

[image: 1]

jupyter, python, scikit-learn

Comment: any typo? maybe you can post with more details?

Comment: hello sir, i wanna try use sklearn.metrics with plot_precision_recall_curve, but my VScode cannot detect my sklearn plot_precision_recall_curve. I have tried uninstalling sklearn and reinstalling it but it still doesn't work. My problems are as in the picture that I have attached

Comment: The name of the function is not correct: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve

Comment: The library you are using has not been updated in years, so likely it does not work with modern sklearn versions.

Comment: [_"API Change: `metrics.PrecisionRecallDisplay` exposes two class methods `from_estimator` and `from_predictions` allowing to create a precision-recall curve using an estimator or the predictions. `metrics.plot_precision_recall_curve` is deprecated in favor of these two class methods and will be removed in 1.2."_](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v1.0.html).

Answer (score 2):

That function is from an old version of scikit-learn.

You can try using **scikit-plot**

*Installation*

> pip install scikit-plot

*Import library*

```
# Import scikit-plot
import scikitplot as skplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

skplt.metrics.plot_precision_recall(y, y_pred)
plt.show()
```

Documentation: https://scikit-plot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/metrics.html#scikitplot.metrics.plot_precision_recall

Or you can use `precision_recall_curve` in the current version of sklearn as mentioned by [Dr. Snoopy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349130/dr-snoopy)

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
```

Answer (score 1):

Following rickhg12hs comment, this is the way to plot precision recall curves from sklearn version 1.2.

First you generate some data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import PrecisionRecallDisplay
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X, y = make_classification(random_state=0)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, random_state=0)
```

Then you train a classifier:

```
clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

You obtain the preditions of the classiffier and with that you can plot the curve with `from_predictions`:

```
y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_predictions(
   y_test, y_pred)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Alternatively: `PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_estimator(clf, X_test, y_test)`